# UICollectionView mosaic layout

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

I need to create a mosaic layout for an app. It would be wonderful to have a completely dynamic layout, similar to the one in the pic below:

[image]

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout) that is really cool, but allows to have only dynamic height. Is there some library out there or is there a way to achieve this result? 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you done it already?
How did you solve it?

Comment: you can use this library:-https://github.com/vinnyoodles/mosaic-layout

Comment: https://medium.com/@cp-satish-v/mosaic-layout-with-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewcompositionallayout-6e4b668503bf