# iOS: Mosaic Layout using collection view in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to implement mosaic layout using collection view as given below in **Objective C**. I have referred StackOverFlow quetion [UICollectionView mosaic layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791197/uicollectionview-mosaic-layout) to implement mosaic layout as given in attached image but not able to find proper solutions. I have also used to refer this [link](https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout) but not able to solve my problem. Can any one show me the right way from where I can start to implement such functionality? Your help would be appreciate. [image: Mosaic Layout]

Comment: Is there any logic behind that? It seems to be 2, 3 (2 and Big one), 3, 3 (Big one and 2), 3,  3 (2 and Big one). So apart from the first line, the rest is identical? Pattern to define? If you know the pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat/43409440#43409440 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364859/cells-order-in-uicollectionview/42365978#42365978

Comment: @Larme, yes there is a recursive pattern where in The first block will be 2 big, 3(2 small & 1 big),3,3(1 Big & 2 Small),3. This pattern will be repeated in the same order again.

Comment: @Larme, Thanks for the reply. I have one confusion in "-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size" method. I found that you are assigning property of self.unitSize with "CGSizeMake(size.width/3,150);". Here, in CGSizeMake which size do I use?

Comment: In your case, you may not want to use only one unitSize but various ones. The first line is divided by two, so it's different. The line with 3 (2 small one big), doesn't have the same width (it's not aligned with the one with 3 all aligned, more 1/4, 3/4), whereas the line with 3 (one big two small is at 1/3, 2/3). I'd recommend to do a for loop, with "really hard coded" values (you calculate each frame one by one). Then, try to factorize the code to understand patterns, how is calculate the height/width of each cells, and then you should guess some units sizes.

Comment: https://medium.com/@cp-satish-v/mosaic-layout-with-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewcompositionallayout-6e4b668503bf

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout with respect to subclassing notes in [UICollectionViewLayout documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout). And the size calculation part for every cell depends on your specific needs.